# How to add a touch screen overlay to a laptop to provide a cheap touch screen solution

Tags: laptop, windows, touchscreen

I do software and know nothing of the arcane ways of screwdrivers, soldering irons and such like.

I see things like this [ZhiYuSun 17" 4 wire resistive USB touch panel overlay kit](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/355mm-288mm-17-Inch-Touch-Screen-panels-4-wire-resistive-USB-touch-panel-overlay-kit-Free/32605104156.html)

[image: image of ZhiYuSun 355mm*288mm 17 Inch Touch Screen panels 4 wire resistive USB touch panel overlay kit]

Can I just attach this to my laptop screen and simply plug in the USB? I suspect not - would it not need device drivers?

So, my question is, is there anything which I can attach to my 17" Windows laptop to convert it to touchscreen, without the need for any complicated setup?

Comment: I expect that the fit of this overlay to a laptop screen not designed for it would not work well. I also am not sure that the connector is an actual USB connector such as thumb drives and other USB devices have. It looks like it is instead designed for a specialty connector which is wired like a USB or has the same pinout as a USB connector and this is designed to plug into a fitting on a motherboard or a controller card. See this youtube video [How to install touch screen kit overlay on a LCD monitor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnaMV3_6Cyk).

Comment: See also [Resistive Touch Screen to USB Mouse Controller - AR1100](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1580) from Adafruit. Then this article [How to Convert an LCD to a Touch Screen](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-convert-an-lcd-to-a-touch-screen). Also an older article with a Lenovo netbook and Hoda Technology Solderless Touch Screen Kit [How to Convert a Netbook Into a Touchscreen PC](http://www.popularmechanics.com/technology/gadgets/how-to/a5144/4339778/).

Comment: If you are going to move forward with this I would really appreciate if you answer your own question with details about the equipment you used, what you did, and how it turned out. I am considering doing something similar by taking an LCD display, removing it from the housing and mounting it in a wooden frame along with a touchscreen overlay and a Raspberry Pi 3. Then running software with the Raspberry Pi using the touchscreen for the human interface. I tried a Perixx PERIPAD-501B touchpad with Raspbian and Windows 10 on a PC and it worked great.

Comment: I will do so, if I go forward. I am still contemplating :-)

Comment: There are several different technologies used with touchscreen overlays and each does provide particular advantages and disadvantages. Some work with gloved hands, for instance, while others work poorly with gloved hands. And the operating environment as far as noise and dust can also make a difference. Then there is the consideration as to whether the overlay and controller are designed for multi-touch or not.

Comment: Just a laptop on a sofa will do for me, but that does sound interesting. Feel free to expound, for the benefit of future readers